# RDS instance recovery for reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, restore, amazon-rds, reserved

I am investigating disaster recovery for an RDS database.

If I want to use a snapshot or point-in-time recovery for my DB instance, naturally a new instance is created.

My instance is a reserved instance, would the resulting instance also be a reserved instance or an on-demand instance? Or can I make the new instance use the reserved instance and then delete the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reservations aren't tied to specific servers. Your current server isn't really a "reserved instance". It is simply an instance that matches your reservation, thus you are being charged less. If you removed it and created another server that matches your reservation, you would get the price discount on the new instance.

Comment: Thanks for claring that up. Yet, the instance matching the reservation is still running of course, so the new one would be on demand.

A) Can I make the second instance run as reserved after deleting the first?
B) I will lose my automatic snapshots of the first instance when I do this right?

Comment: The reservation just checks that you have an instance that matches the reservation parameters. If you delete the first instance, but the second instance matches the reservation, then the second instance will automatically start being charged at the reservation price.

Comment: Yes all automatic RDS snapshots from an instance will be deleted when you delete the instance.

Comment: Thank you Mark, that perfectly answered my question.